# Closure of regular coordinate ball is homeomorphic to the closure of its Euclidean ball?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Lee in Introduction to Topological Manifolds defines regular coordinate balls as follows:

"Let $M$ be a $n$-manifold. We say that a coordinate ball $B\subset M$ is a regular coordinate ball if there is a neighbourhood $B'$ of $\overline{B}$ and a homeomorphism $\varphi:B'\to B_{r'}(x)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that takes $B$ to $B_r(x)$ and $\overline{B}$ to $\overline{B_r(x)}$ for some $r'>r>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$."

I was wondering if this means that $B\cong B_r(x)$ and $\overline{B}\cong\overline{B_r(x)}$? I know that restricting $\varphi$ to $B$, I get a continuous injective map $B\to B_{r'}(x)$, which gives a continuous bijection $B\to B_r(x)$. Here I used $f:X\to Y$ continuous, $A\subset X$ implies $f|_{A}:A\to f(A)$ is continuous. Similarly, I can show there is a continuous bijection $\overline{B}\to \overline{B_r(x)}$ upon restricting $\varphi$ to $\overline{B}$.

I am having trouble showing that the inverse map is also continuous. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This seems to be a consequence of [the invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), which implies that any continuous bijection between open subsets of euclidean space is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for the suggestion:)) It certainly is useful, but I haven't seen a lot of algebraic topology at this point and was hoping for a less technical route.

Comment: I don't think you will find an easier answer. While this sounds intuitive, the actual proof is likely to be related (if not equivalent) to the invariance of domain. And this theorem is known to be easy to understand but difficult to prove.

Comment: I see. In that case, maybe I will black-box this for now and come back to it later. Thanks tho :))